# How to freeze ComboBox Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I am writing a script on an Excel VBA `UserForm`. The form has three different fields that are `ComboBox` to be filled in by the user. I want to make the contents of `ComboBox 3` dependent on what is inputted in `Combobox2`.

`ComboBox2` is populated as follows:

```
  With ComboBox2
        .AddItem "Legal Information"
        .AddItem "Media"
        .AddItem "Official Disclosures"
        .AddItem "Patents and Trademarks"
        .AddItem "Private Corporate Information"
        .AddItem "Private Individual Information"
        .AddItem "Property Information"
        .AddItem "Public Company Information"
        .AddItem "Public Tenders"
        .AddItem "Ships, Vessels and Aircraft Information"
        .AddItem "Watchlists/Blacklists"
    End With
```

Depending on what the user inputs in `ComboBox2`, `ComboBox3` is populated by different options. I am doing such as follows:

```
Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()

Dim index As Integer
 index = ComboBox2.ListIndex

 ComboBox3.Clear

Select Case index
     Case Is = 0
         With ComboBox3
             .AddItem "Administrative"
             .AddItem "Civil"
             .AddItem "Criminal"
         End With
     Case Is = 1
         With ComboBox3
             .AddItem "Arts and Culture"
             .AddItem "Blog/Social Media"
             .AddItem "Business and Economics"
             .AddItem "General News"
             .AddItem "Intelligence and Security"
             .AddItem "Official News Agency/Official Press"
             .AddItem "Energy"
             .AddItem "Pharmaceutical and Medical News"
             .AddItem "Politics"
             .AddItem "Religion"
             .AddItem "Society, Lifestyle and Opinion"
             .AddItem "Sport"
         End With

End Sub
```

I'd like for`ComboBox3` to be frozen, i.e., impossible for the user to fill in, in case any other of the options of `ComboBox2` is selected - in the event `Case is = 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10`. How should I do this. Thank you.

Comment: `ComboBox3.Enabled = False`?

Comment: Lock it using .locked, or diable it using .enabled

Comment: FWIW `Case Is = 0` can be written more simply as `Case 0`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. That works!
I've just then inserted a `ComboBox3.Enabled = True` after each `Case Is =` so that `ComboBox3` "unfreezes" if the user changes the selection. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As prescribed in the comments, `ComboBox3` is "frozen" with `ComboBox3.Enabled = False`. However, in order to avoid the case where a user "freezes" the `ComboBox` and then selects another option in `ComboBox2`, it is necessary to insert a `ComboBox3.Enabled = True` before each index case.

The corrected code is below.

```
Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()

Dim index As Integer
 index = ComboBox2.ListIndex

 ComboBox3.Clear

Select Case index
    Case Is = 0
        ComboBox3.Enabled = True
        With ComboBox3
            .AddItem "Administrative"
            .AddItem "Civil"
            .AddItem "Criminal"
        End With
    Case Is = 1
        ComboBox3.Enabled = True
        With ComboBox3
            .AddItem "Arts and Culture"
            .AddItem "Blog/Social Media"
            .AddItem "Business and Economics"
            .AddItem "General News"
            .AddItem "Intelligence and Security"
            .AddItem "Official News Agency/Official Press"
            .AddItem "Energy"
            .AddItem "Pharmaceutical and Medical News"
            .AddItem "Politics"
            .AddItem "Religion"
            .AddItem "Society, Lifestyle and Opinion"
            .AddItem "Sport"
        End With
    Case Is = 2
        ComboBox3.Enabled = False
    Case Is = 3
        ComboBox3.Enabled = False
    Case Is = 4
        ComboBox3.Enabled = False
    Case Is = 5
        ComboBox3.Enabled = False
    Case Is = 6
        ComboBox3.Enabled = False
    Case Is = 7
        ComboBox3.Enabled = False
    Case Is = 8
        ComboBox3.Enabled = False
    Case Is = 9
        ComboBox3.Enabled = False
    Case Is = 10
        ComboBox3.Enabled = False
End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: You can add `ComboBox3.Enabled = False` just after `ComboBox3.Clear`, to start with that cmb disabled. And instead of listing all other cases (2, 3, 4, etc), just write `Case Else`

Answer (score 1):

use "MatchRequired" of the combobox, set it to TRUE, then the user can select or type only the items existing in the combobox. no need to freeze it.